# Possible to save a file in AutoHotKey script?

Tags: copy, autohotkey

i want to save a .png file in to a AutoHotKey script, so that when i run the script it make the .png file.

i tryed to open the .png with notepad++ and copy the text in to a FileAppend command but there are just to many """ and "%" characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tested (1) and (2), but here are three different approaches:

1. modifying AutoHotkeySC.bin with a third-party tool like ressource hacker
2. [building a .dll which you then might access via ahk](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/57631-crazy-scripting-resource-only-dll-for-dummies-36l-v07/)
3. [pack the complete file into your script and start its creation upon function calling](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64481-include-virtually-any-file-in-a-script-exezipdlletc/). I saved this guy's V2.3 script up to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EX0qrqwK). Works perfectly fine for me.

regards